# Как продолжить цикл, если выполнение идет внутри(неправильно)

Tags: java, циклы

Имеется метод,

```
    int size = 0;
    int[] Name= new int[size];
    String contName;
    int[] unkSize = new int[5];
    String unkName;
in.seek(NameOffset); //NameOffset==64
for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
{   
    for(int i=0;i<1;i++) {
        size = (int)in.read();
    }

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        Name[i]= (int)in.read();
        contName+=(char)Name[i];
    }

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        unkSize [i]=(int)in.read();
        unkName += (int)unkSize [i];
    }
}
```

который использует 3 цикла, для чтения данных - определенным образом,выглядит он следующим образом:

1. 1 Loop, читает интовое значение - равное от 0 до 1, и записывает его
   в буфер-переменную.
2. 2 Loop, читает от 0 до значения равного - из переменной(loop1) и
   присваивает результат в Буфер-переменную(2).
3. 3 Loop, читает int от 0 до 5, и присваивает значение в
   переменную(3). Таким образом, если в начале чтения FilePointer,
   указывал - на позицию 64(внутри файла), то после этих 3ех циклов,
   позиция стала равна 74,

И вся проблема заключается в том что если обернуть эти 3 цикла - еще одним, то метод не перейдет на 75 строку, и не начнет снова выполнять эти 3 цикла, но с переходом, а вместо этого они будут выполняют себя внутри, то есть просчитывая снова size, который будет вместо 5, равен 6(на позиции 65), и так до - того значения которое указано в основном Loop'e. А мне нужно чтобы этот метод прошел c 64 по 74, проделав работу,и перешел уже на 75-85++,и проделал там работу, а не выполнял цикл внутри себя.

Возможно ли это решить - добавив, boolean переменную, которая бы указывала true, для циклов, после чего они переходили далее, если да то как именно это следует сделать, и если это бред то что можно сделать - не сильно портя код!

Comment: Простите, а для чего первый цикл? `for(int i=0;i<1;i++)`?

Comment: Вы понимаете, конечно, что никаких номеров строк никто не видит?

Comment: `int size; int[] Name= new int[size];` Странно, что это вообще откомпилировалось. `size` должен быть definitely assigned (kak eto po-russki?)

Comment: Какой поток сознания однако...

Comment: в принципе просто счетчик. Вот позиция откуда начинается чтение, 05 4e 6f 6e 65 00 10 04 07 04 - она равна 64, Заканчивается тут 05 6f 62 6a 30, но работа этих 3 циклов не повторяется для 05 6f 62 6a 30, а повторяется для 05 4e 6f 6e 65...

Comment: "если обернуть эти 3 цикла - еще одним". Хм. Дайте не тот код, который работает, а тот, который НЕ работает.

Comment: int size;
        int[] Name= new int[size];
        String contName;
        int[] unkSize = new int[5];
        String unkName;
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
     for(int i=0;i<1;i++)
           {
               size = (int)in.read();
           }
   for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
           {
               Name[i]= (int)in.read();
               contName+=(char)Name[i];
           }
   for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
           {
               unkSize [i]=(int)in.read();
               unkName += (int)unkSize [i];
           }
    }

Comment: @LightFusion: Понятнее не стало. Может, отредактируйте вопрос?

Comment: @VladD Готово!!

Comment: @LightFusion: А теперь гляньте, что получилось. Форматирование опять слетело же.

Comment: добавил! как надо,

Comment: @LightFusion: А ещё никто из нас не понял, что такое 75-ая строка. Вы говорите о ней в вопросе: ..."то метод не перейдет на 75 строку"

Comment: =) понятно, 75 строка это строка от начала файла, после прохождения 3ех циклов, забыл добавить указатель(он равен 64). Точнее не строка а - байт(указатель), значение которого указывает - на размер идущей за ним строки.

Comment: @LightFusion: Окей, стало немного яснее. Давайте по-другому. Напишите, какой у вас формат данных (наверное, интересно начиная с 64-го символа), тогда возможно станет понятнее, что нужно делать, и что вы делаете неправильно.

Comment: @VladD - впечатлен Вашим желанием помочь человеку, который, обращаясь за помощью, не может внятно объяснить, чего он хочет

Comment: На сколько я знаю это контейнер имен, int size, String Name, int unk, имеет такой формат. {05} {None {00 10 04 07 04 }, размер(Int size) всегда постоянен и не меняется, unk Так же. Я так понимаю вы об этом или об другом ?

Comment: @ Igor, Ну куда внятнее - я не так силен в Java, чтобы объяснить еще более правильнее. Но тот код что я добавил, работает не правильно - цилк не переходит дальше, к примеру вот это читается {05} {None} {00 10 04 07 04 }, а это {08} {Default}{ 00 10 04 07 04 0d} идет далее, но не читается - используя тот Loop что я сделал, как правильно создать цикл - чтобы читалось далее.

Comment: @LightFusion: Угу, об этом, но я, честно говоря, всё равно ничего не понял. Что у вас обозначают фигурные скобки?

Comment: VladD - да ничего не означает, это я для вас отделил чтобы нагляднее было видно где-что, их там нету все идет так: 05 4e 6f 6e 65 00 10 04 07 04 08 44 65 66 61 75 6c 74 00 10 04 07 04, `4e 6f 6e 65` это None, мой код считает побайтово каждый символ и переобразует в строку, 44 65 66 61 75 6c 74 это Default .

Comment: @LightFusion: Ага, понятно. А `{ None }` — это 4 символа, да?

Comment: @Igor: Я когда-то тоже не очень умел задавать вопросы :-) И мне помогали.

Comment: да 4 Байтовых символа, мой код все читает, только дальше он не продолжает читать, а начинает заного все эти байты просчитывать, но к примеру вместо 5 он читает 4e, а 4e Это буква N, которая вообще не должна присваиваться, а она присваивается в следующий цикл, и получается такая гадость, ввиду того что я обернул все эти 3 цикла в 1.

Comment: Еще забыл добавить*, от - значения  которое указывает размер строки в байтах, отнимается единица, то есть в моем примере там 5-1, то есть 4 байта, и следующий код(цикл) читает N o n e;

Comment: @LightFusion: Окей, с частью разобрались. А что идёт за `{ 05 } { None }`?

Comment: После идет unk это 4 байта(такого вида `{10 04 07 04
}` но это если учитывать что от 05 отняли 1, а иначе там 00 10 04 07 04, и если они будут читаться как 4 байта 04 в конце не будет записываться, но размер их постоянный, то есть 5-7байт не будет,

Comment: @LightFusion: то есть потом идёт 5 байт, правильно? И они нам по идее не нужны, правильно? То есть их можно не записывать в переменную. Или всё-таки нужны?

Comment: VladD, Они нужны для перехода на - байт указывающий размер следующей строки, ведь если их не читать, FilePointer, будет указывать на позицию, того байта который прочел в конце, то есть последний байт строки, и  если это так то - будет выводиться 10 из Unk, и это не то что надо.

Comment: @LightFusion: Это да, вычитывать их надо, но хранить, судя по всему, нет. Обновил ответ, смотрите.

Comment: @VladD, а вы не забыли  in.seek(Offset); ? Чтение начинается не с начала файла, а с позиции указанной в переменной, в моем случае это 64, где ее следует размещать - внутри цикла или за ним ?

Comment: @LightFusion: Угу, ещё это надо в начале.

Comment: А какую вы яву использует, у меня skip, отмечен как Undefinied! `The method skip(int) is undefined for the type RandomAccessFile`

Comment: @LightFusion: `skip` [должен быть](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#skip%28long%29) по идее.

Comment: @VladD, skipBytes, есть ), но всеравно дело решилось - спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте править по частям, возможно, придём к верному ответу.

Во-первых, `size` не является константой, поэтому выделять массив размером в `size` заранее не имеет смысла. Получаем такой кусок:

```
int size = in.read();
int[] Name = new int[size];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    Name[i] = (int)in.read();
    contName += (char)Name[i];
}
```

---

Далее, исходя из комментария, размер нужно уменьшить на 1. Уточнённый код:

```
int size = in.read() - 1;
int[] Name = new int[size];
String contName = "";

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    Name[i] = (int)in.read();
    contName += (char)Name[i];
}
```

---

Окей, дальше идёт 5 байт, которые вроде бы одинаковые всегда. То есть, их можно скипнуть. Так и делаем. Заодно оборачиваем в цикл:

```
in.seek(NameOffset); //NameOffset==64

for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

    int size = in.read() - 1;
    int[] Name = new int[size]; // а нужен ли этот массив?
    String contName = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Name[i] = (int)in.read();
        contName += (char)Name[i];
    }

    in.skip(5); // когда заработает, не забудьте
                // добавить проверку на конец данных
}
```

Непонятно, что делать с прочитанными данными. Но тут уж ТС разберётся сам.

Comment: Все работает! спасибо вам огромное, я драк несколько часов с этим мучался, как видно я плохо умею оборачивать все в Loop =), спасибо.

Comment: @LightFusion: Пожалуйста!

Comment: Не хочу снова создавать - тему, но как мне сделать чтобы ContName Была Global переменной, и входящие в нее имена принимали индекс(0)ObjName1 ,(1)ObjName2, (2)ObjName3 и тд; Так как сейчас если сделать ContName Global переменной, она будет принимать - все объекты в один индекс- то есть, (0)ObjName1ObjName2ObjName3 ид, вместо того чтобы быть разделены!

Comment: @LightFusion: Тогда заведите глобальный список `List<String> ContNames = new ArrayList<String>`, и в конце каждой итерации цикла добавляйте текущий экземпляр `contName` в конец спискаю

Comment: Спасибо что наконец ответили, а можно это как то сделать по другому - не прибегая к этим сложным Массивам, - создав своего рода Set Метод, внутри тела кода, который бы наполнял Global переменную правильный образом. Моя задача состоит в том чтобы, обратиться к тем объектам(именам) - используя Индекс, но желательно не прибегать к использованию массива - это возможно ?

Comment: @LightFusion: Добавить в список — это самый простой возможный метод, проще не может быть. Если надо запомнить несколько значений, как обойтись одной строкой?

Comment: У меня выскакивает ошибка при импорте `Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s) `  . И каким другим способом можно это решить - более сложным, но без использования List, возможно ли добавить  `(char)Name[i]` , в глобальный массив строк(String[] ) по определенному правилу - в теле кода, не присваиваая напрямую в строку ?

Comment: По поводу ошибки, вероятно, имеет смысл задать отдельный вопрос. Наверняка опечатка. Всё равно умение работать с `List<T>` пригодится вам ещё миллион раз. Можно, в принципе, использовать сразу список без промежуточной переменной, выбор ваш.

Comment: использовать сразу список без промежуточной переменной, а каким образом это можно сделать ?

Comment: все разобрался еще раз спасибо, но все-таки душа мучает =) вопросом -  как это можно сделать не прибегая к List array ? - обычным старым способом!

Comment: @LightFusion: О, хорошо, что разобрались. Для меня с промежуточной строкой и есть обычный старый способ. Можно было бы по идее не заводить новую строку, а в начале итерации добавить пустую строку в list или там массив, и пользоваться ей с доступом по индексу.

Comment: здравствуйте еще раз,  хотел все-таки узнать на счет обычного способа, можно ведь создать класс конструктор и сделать его массивом - для моих объектов ? Так ведь ? Вот так `class myObjects{
  int obj1,obj2;
  int ob3,obj4; 
 }`  И потом объявить глобал переменную     `public myObjects[] myObj;`  И дальше работать с самим конструктором `myObj[i].obj1 = in.read();` - конечно предварительно его объявив как New myobj ? А дальше уже через цилк можно загрузить все объеты из моей глобал переменной myObjects - Так ведь ?

Comment: @LightFusion: В принципе, можно. Смотрите сами, не будет ли код слишком запутанным при этом.

Comment: я наоборот пытаюсь сделать его как можно проще - без использования сторонних библиотек, хочу правильно обучиться =), а это не просто! - так что спасибо еще раз!

Comment: @LightFusion: Пожалуйста!